# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgRGm/77/)

My html and js works fine in JSFiddle. But its giving error in the console in my rails app

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined admin.js:1000
Chosen.result_select admin.js:1000
Chosen.search_results_mouseup admin.js:1000
(anonymous function) admin.js:1000
x.event.dispatch admin.js:6
v.handle`

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-3 equ">
       <select class = "car-select col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 center boxalign" id = "brand">
          <option value="brand">Brand Select</option>
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes1">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          <option value="volvo2">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </div>

  <div class="col-xs-3 equ">
       <select class = "car-select col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 center boxalign" id = "car">
          <option value="brand" class = "mercedes">Brand Select</option>
          <option value="volvo" class = "mercedes">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab" class = "volvo">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes" class = "volvo">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi" class = "volvo">Audi</option>
          <option value="volvo" class = "mercedes">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab" class = "mercedes">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes" class = "mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi" class = "mercedes">Audi</option>
        </select>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".car-select").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10});
$(".car-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true}); 
  $(function() {
    $("#car").chained("#brand"); 
    $("#brand").trigger("liszt:updated");   
    $("#brand").bind("change", function(){
    $("#car").trigger("liszt:updated")
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question, but it I got the same error recently.
I fixed this adding an empty option tag, like this:

```
<select class = "car-select col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 center boxalign" id = "car">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="brand" class = "mercedes">Brand Select</option>
      <option value="volvo" class = "mercedes">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab" class = "volvo">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes" class = "volvo">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi" class = "volvo">Audi</option>
      <option value="volvo" class = "mercedes">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab" class = "mercedes">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes" class = "mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi" class = "mercedes">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: same error here. sadly an empty option tag didnt fix it :/

Comment: Even though it may seem counterintuitive, this will also work if you are using ng-options=""  So, use both ng-options and add one single empty option tag `<option value=""></option>`

Answer (score 2):

Adding
`<option disabled></option>`
to your list will solve the error.